# Chrome Extension Popup Dom Changes not updating

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, zurb-foundation

I've build a chrome extension that simply displays some HTML in the Popup. I use the foundation framework to display tables and jQuery to manipulate the DOM

Both JQuery and Foundation are downloaded to the extension and included in the HTML.

When I try to update the tables while the popup is already open, I don't see the changes in the Popup changing (e.g $('p').text("new text") ) - but in the Elements section of the Chrome Dev tools the text was changes.

Also my CSS hover effect on the table rows only display on the upper two of the three tables.

Is this something that is normal? I don't have these issues when I view the popup.html in a separate tab.

How often does the DOM get updated? How can I control when it does?

Here is my popup.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/what-input.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<link href="../../css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table class="hover unstriped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="200">Table Header</th>
            <th>Table Header</th>
            <th width="150">Table Header</th>
            <th width="150">Table Header</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content Goes Here</td>
                        <td>Content Goes Here</td>
                    </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<table class="hover unstriped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="200">Table Header</th>
            <th>Table Header</th>
            <th width="150">Table Header</th>
            <th width="150">Table Header</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content Goes Here</td>
            <td>Content Goes Here</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<table class="hover unstriped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="200">Table Header</th>
            <th>Table Header</th>
            <th width="150">Table Header</th>
            <th width="150">Table Header</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Content</td>
                        <td>Content Goes Here</td>
                        <td>Content Goes Here</td>
                    </tr>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p id="test">new message</p>
```

EDIT
Screencast: http://youtu.be/7xMwisRWHJE 
You can see 1. The hover effect only works on the first two tables and 2. the jQuery command changes the node in the Elements panel, but not in the popup itself

manifest.json

```
    {
      "name": "CHANGE THIS : Extension boilerplate",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "This extension was created with the awesome extensionizr.com",
      "homepage_url": "http://extensionizr.com",
      "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
      },
      "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "browser action demo",
        "default_popup": "src/browser_action/popup.html"
      },
      "default_locale": "en",
      "permissions": [
        "https://*/*"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) or at least a screencast it's hard to guess.

Comment: we didn't get your point what you want to say if there is an exception that script on DOM element is not working then you should use like $(document).find('p').text("new text") possible thing is that it will work

Comment: Show your manifest.json, html and js files.

Comment: Just adding fuel to the fire here - I'm also having a very similar issue, in that the react app works fine in a regular tab and even renders in the chrome extension popup initially, it's just that the DOM manipulation that react does to update UI components (adding divs on mouseover)) or hover css aren't getting painted / rendered to screen even though they are getting updated in the DOM tree. It's only when I move my mouse over the Elements section in dev tool does it get painted to screen. This is on my primary Mac. Other machines (Mac and Win) work fine with same extension build.

Comment: New information - this problem _only_ exists on my external monitor! Explains why it works fine on my other machines.

Comment: I am getting the same issue as @Sean. Any idea why and how can this be fixed?

Comment: I ran into the same issue as well. Paints are getting skipped in the popup when using an external monitor on my MacBook.

Anyone figured this out yet?

Comment: Totally insane @Sean!

Great find that the problem is monitor dependent. Crazy Chrome bug!

Comment: I also ran into the exact same issue. As @Sean mentioned, this only happen on external monitor. Has anyone filed a bug to Chromium yet?

Comment: I have not Greg. That’s a very sensible thing to do.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=971701 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500742/why-is-my-google-chrome-extensions-popup-ui-laggy-on-external-monitors-but-not/64113061 More concretely, the solution with a forced redraw has helped me to solve a similar issue.