# Why is my Chrome extension is faster during performance profiling?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a basic extension that contains 3 input fields.
When I type at most bottom (the third) input - its content text is updated super slow (after a few seconds / after I focus out of the input).

I wanted to measure the extension's performance to understand the root cause of the issue using Chrome devtools, so I clicked on `Inspect Popup`, opened the `Performance` tab, and clicked on `start profiling` (the grey circle button on the top left). Then the magic happened -> as long as the session was recorded all the inputs started to work super fast! when I stopped the profiling, the problematic input started to react slowly again.

Why when I record and profile the extension it works faster? Is there a configuration that changes using the profiling time?

> ```
> ####popup.html####
>    
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html><head>
> <meta charset="utf-8" />   </head>   <body>
> <div id="app"></div>
> <input>
> <input>
> <input>   </body> </html>
> ```

> ```
> manifest.json
> {
>
> "name": "NAME",
> "version": "0.0.0",
> "manifest_version": 2,
> "key": ...,
> "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://unpkg.com; object-src 'self'",
> "icons": {
>   "128": "images/icon-128.png"
> },
> "background": {
>   "page": "background.html"
> },
> "browser_action": {
>   "default_icon": "images/icon-128.png",
>   "default_title": "Title",
>   "default_popup": "popup.html"
> }   }
> ```

> ```
> background.html
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
> <!-- <script type="module" src="background.bundle.js"></script> -->   </head>   <body></body> </html>
> ```

have some extra webpack conf files but don't think they are relevant.
The rest of the code is commented out as I'm trying to understand the behavior of the input.

[as long as this screen is showed - the inputs worked fast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3A29.png)

Comment: {
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "key": "#######",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://unpkg.com; object-src 'self'",
  "icons": {
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon-128.png",
    "default_title": "Title",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}

Comment: done. thanks. to note that i have many more files with the js code (its a react app) but i commented everything out in order to understand why more than 2 inputs stuck the application

Comment: It might be a bug in Chrome. What's your OS and display configuration?

Comment: macOS Big Sur (11.6) resolution - default for display

Comment: No external display then? If there is, see https://crbug.com/971701.

Comment: OMG . you are right. it happens only at an external screen (didnt understand that this is the meaning of display configuration).
on my native mac screen it works smoothy.
thank you so much @wOxxOm ive debugged during the whole weekend

Comment: In that case it's a duplicate of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500742/why-is-my-google-chrome-extensions-popup-ui-laggy-on-external-monitors-but-not) that has a workaround.

Comment: BTW is there anything i can do in order to remediate it?

Comment: but the workaround there is to remove the background.js but i need it (?)

Comment: No, the workaround is in that topic's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64113061).

Comment: thank you SO MUCH
i'm highly highly appreciate it

Comment: Another reason: when devtools is open, the app is slow, when you start profiling, devtools is apparently put on hold. I had the same with my application. Closing devtools made the app smooth again.